# OS X: How do I effectively find text with surrounding 100 characters context in 600mb json file?

Tags: macos, grep

I have a large minified `text.json` file in which I need to find a specific phrase `dasdhfb347rbf` and print out the surrounding e.g. 100 characters context (leading/tailing).

I have tried `grep -Eo '.{0,100}dasdhfb347rbf.{0,100}' /dir/text.json` but it just seems to hang for ever.

PS. I have a macbook with an i7 cpu, 8GB ram and an SSD drive.

Comment: Try `grep -Eo` for extended regexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mark Setchell points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43230341/45375), your use of (unescaped) `{` and `}` in `.{0,100}` to match up to 100 chars. requires use of `-E` to enable *extended* regexes (regular expressions); alternatively, you could have used escaping (with the default *basic* regexes): `.\{0,100\}`.

However, neither correction solves your problem, which is **a *performance* problem**: To `grep`, **the entire file - because it is *minified* JSON - is a *single line***, and **your particular regex results in a surprisingly long execution time** (depending on your hardware, on the order of 10+ *minutes* with a 600MB file; presumably, your regex requires a lot of *backtracking*).

Using `LC_ALL=C`, as suggested in [Yreg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43229199/45375), brings a slight improvement, but not enough to make a real difference (`LC_ALL=C` simplifies character handling, because every single byte is then assumed to be an ASCII character).

Switching to *literal* string matching improves performance drastically, but while `grep` does support literal matching, it doesn't support reporting *character*-based context (only line-based).

**The tool to use is therefore `awk`**, which offers functions for literal string matching and position-based substring extraction:

```sh
awk -v RS='\3' -v txt='dasdhfb347rbf' -v n=100 '
  BEGIN { 
    getline; s = $0               # read the entire file
    while (pos=index(s, txt)) {   # loop over matches
      len = length(txt) + 2 * n - (pos - n < 1 ? n - pos + 1 : 0)
      print substr(s, pos-n, len)
      s = substr(s, pos -n + len)
    }
  }
' text.json
```

The above should perform much better.

Note that `v RS='\3'` is needed to make BSD Awk read the entire file at once (`-v RS='^$'` is typically used with GNU Awk and Mawk, but that doesn't work with BSD Awk); note that this technique relies on control character `0x3` not being part of the text.

On a side note:

- *GNU* Awk, which you can install via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), is more than twice as fast than the stock BSD Awk on my machine.
- [Mawk](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/) (also installable via Homebrew), which is generally the fastest Awk, is not an option here, because it seems to have a hard limit on the line length.

Comment: What a great answer!

Comment: Took like 1 minute to run :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the locale.

`LC_ALL=C grep -o…`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `-E` option on macOS to permit use of extended regexes:

```
# without "-E", finds nothing
echo abcdefghijk | grep -o ".def.{3}"

# with "-E", finds regex
echo abcdefghijk | grep -Eo ".def.{3}"
cdefghi
```